# Trying to get data from wsdl using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

I have this c# code where i am trying to get data from a wsdl in visual studio .
The code is okay but when i try to get the data to written on notepad it just shows an empty space :

```
WindowsService1.ServiceReference1.GetModifiedBookingsOperationResponse getModbkgsResp;
using (var proxy = new WindowsService1.ServiceReference1.InventoryServiceClient())
{
    int noofBookings = 1;
    getModbkgsResp = proxy.GetModifiedBookings(getModBkgsReq);
    WindowsService1.ServiceReference1.Booking[] bookings = new WindowsService1.ServiceReference1.Booking[noofBookings];
    getModbkgsResp.Bookings = new WindowsService1.ServiceReference1.Booking[noofBookings];
    getModbkgsResp.Bookings = bookings;
    if (getModbkgsResp.Bookings != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bookings.Length; i++)
        {

            Booking bk = new WindowsService1.ServiceReference1.Booking();
            getModbkgsResp.Bookings[i] = bk;
            if (bk != null )
            {
                bookingSource = bk.BookingSource;
                if (bk.BookingId == Bookingcode)
                {
                    this.WriteToFile("Booking Source =" + bookingSource + "");
                }
                else
                {
                    this.WriteToFile("Sorry could not find your source of booking");

                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.WriteToFile("Looks like source is null " );

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.WriteToFile("ERROR: Booking details not returned from GetModifiedBookings! " +StartDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code? Do you think it could be important to show the definition of `WriteToFile`? If the question is related to something failing to be written to a file it seems to me that it would be important to see the actual code that does the writing to the file.

Comment: You seem to be calling `GetModifiedBookings` but then overwriting the response's `Bookings` array with a new one. What is the logic behind that? Yes, they will all be blank when you do that.

Comment: Also, have you confirmed that `bookings.Length` is greater than 0?

Comment: @JasonBoyd below is the code for the writetoFile:                                                         
    private void WriteToFile(string text)
        {
            string path = "C:\\ServiceLog.txt";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Format(text, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")));
                writer.Close();
            }
        }

Comment: @JohnWu okay will try to ammend that and advice about the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using the `new` keyword to create items that should have been retrieved from the service. Naturally anything created with `new` will be initialized with default values and will not contain any data that was retrieved from the service.

My guess is your code should look more like this:

```
using (var proxy = new WindowsService1.ServiceReference1.InventoryServiceClient())
{
    var response = proxy.GetModifiedBookings(getModBkgsReq);
    if (response.Bookings == null)
    {
        this.WriteToFile("ERROR: Booking details not returned from GetModifiedBookings! " +StartDate);
        return;
    }
    var booking = response.Bookings.SingleOrDefault( b => b.BookingId == bookingCode);
    if (booking == null)
    {
        this.WriteToFile("Sorry could not find your source of booking");
        return;
    }
    var bookingSource = booking.BookingSource;
    this.WriteToFile("Booking Source =" + bookingSource + "");
}
```

Comment: but it seems that it keeps on returning null with the message "Sorry could not find your source of booking" how do i ensure that it returns something :

Comment: Got me. Could be a bug in the service, or maybe you have the wrong booking number.

Comment: i have even added an existing booking number and still it gives the "Sorry could not find your source of booking"

Comment: i have updated you code and it works i also updated the service reference as well..on visual studio.. and i able to pull bookings/data